# Why is my robot shooting my friends?

Tags: borderlands-2

On occasion Deathtrap will either use his blue thunderbolt or red laser eye attack on me or my friends. I thought maybe this was his "restore 30% of your shields" skill, but the attacks look identical to his normal attacks, and he'll occasionally do it to characters in Fight For Your Life.

Does he just use his normal attacks on you and they happen to heal your shield, or is this a bug or what? Does it do anything if he hits a downed character with this "attack"? How does he prioritize his target?

Answer (score 1):

His "Buck Up" skill, which restores shields, shares the same visual effects as his default ranged attack which looks like a blue thunderbolt.  When being targeted, the recipient may have a visual cue around their screen border.  I have had a coop partner's Deathtrap target me with "Buck Up" even when I was in "FFYL" mode, although I can not confirm whether this had any effect upon gaining "Second Wind".

As a side note, the skill seems to restore more than 30% shields as Deathtrap appears to channel the ability.  Maybe it just triggers the shield recharge and it continues to fill the remainder by itself.  I feel like the skill warrants more inspection as it allows the Mechromancer to be a big team player in coop!